# MongoDb aggregate error "each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object"

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my aggregation code for mongodb collection :

```
$mongo_db_name = "db_".$tenant_id;
$con = new MongoClient($this->config->item('mongo_instance'));
$db = $con->$mongo_db_name;
$collection = $db->$module;        

$options = array('cursor' => array("batchSize" => 4 ));

$pipeline=array(
               array('$match'=>array('deleted'=>'0')),
               array('$group'=>array('_id' => array('id'=>'$id', 'accountnm' => '$account_name', 'legal___corporate_name_cstm' => '$legal___corporate_name_cstm', 'funded_by_cstm' => '$funded_by_cstm', 'approval_amount_cstm' => '$approval_amount_cstm', 'payback_amount_cstm' => '$payback_amount_cstm', 'factor_rate_cstm' => '$factor_rate_cstm', 'daily_ach_amount__1_cstm' => '$daily_ach_amount__1_cstm', 'total_commission_owed_cstm' => '$total_commission_owed_cstm', 'total_commission_paid_cstm' => '$total_commission_paid_cstm', 'upfront_amount_due_cstm' => '$upfront_amount_due_cstm', 'upfront_amount_due_date_cstm' => '$upfront_amount_due_date_cstm', 'date_modified' => '$date_modified'))),
             );
$data = $collection->aggregate($pipeline,$options);

var_dump($data);
```

I am getting this error with the above code

> array (size=4)   'ok' => float 0   'errmsg' => string 'Each element of
>   the 'pipeline' array must be an object' (length=54)   'code' => int 14
>   'codeName' => string 'TypeMismatch' (length=12)

If I try to encode the pipeline using json_encode the result is 'null'. 
If I use `find(array('deleted'=>'0'));` it returns all documents as expected.
Can anyone help me about where I am going wrong or whatmust I do to resolve this ?

Comment: try this one. https://pastebin.com/xsRMhKJ6

Comment: @smoqadam I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation pipeline accepts an array of objects, so your pipeline should be like

```
[
    { $match:{} },
    { $group:{} },
    { $somepipelinestageOperator:{} },
]
```

So, if you have pipeline has anything other than an object (i.e., an array), you will get the above error. For example:

```
[
    [ $match:{} },
    { $group:{} },
    { $somepipelinestageOperator:{} },
]
```

in your code there are array for match and group so its failing.

```
$pipeline=array(
    array('$match'=>array('deleted'=>'0')),
    array('$group'=>array('_id' => array('id'=>'$id', 'accountnm' => '$account_name', 'legal___corporate_name_cstm' => '$legal___corporate_name_cstm', 'funded_by_cstm' => '$funded_by_cstm', 'approval_amount_cstm' => '$approval_amount_cstm', 'payback_amount_cstm' => '$payback_amount_cstm', 'factor_rate_cstm' => '$factor_rate_cstm', 'daily_ach_amount__1_cstm' => '$daily_ach_amount__1_cstm', 'total_commission_owed_cstm' => '$total_commission_owed_cstm', 'total_commission_paid_cstm' => '$total_commission_paid_cstm', 'upfront_amount_due_cstm' => '$upfront_amount_due_cstm', 'upfront_amount_due_date_cstm' => '$upfront_amount_due_date_cstm', 'date_modified' => '$date_modified'))),
);
```

you can print your pipeline and see that your pipeline stages are having array and not object.