# How to show only one of the multiple documents in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to join or call only one document from multiple documents that can be repeated, all this for a unique identifier, in this case `code`, which is a numerical value.

```
[
    {
      "_id": "6386b0e114fe6aee844af06e",
      "transfer": {
        "code": 2,
        "author": {
          "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:29:43.308Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
        },
        "output": {
          "type": "Transfer out",
          "quantity": 3,
          "to": {
            "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        },
        "entry": {
          "type": "Transfer in",
          "quantity": 3,
          "from": {
            "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6386b13e14fe6aee844af06f",
      "transfer": {
        "code": 2,
        "author": {
          "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:29:43.308Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
        },
        "output": {
          "type": "Transfer out",
          "quantity": 3,
          "to": {
            "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        },
        "entry": {
          "type": "Transfer in",
          "quantity": 3,
          "from": {
            "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6386b0e114fe6aee844af06e",
      "transfer": {
        "code": 1,
        "author": {
          "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:27:52.003Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
        },
        "output": {
          "type": "Transfer out",
          "quantity": 1,
          "to": {
            "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        },
        "entry": {
          "type": "Transfer in",
          "quantity": 1,
          "from": {
            "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6386b13e14fe6aee844af06f",
      "transfer": {
        "code": 1,
        "author": {
          "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:27:52.003Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
        },
        "output": {
          "type": "Transfer out",
          "quantity": 1,
          "to": {
            "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        },
        "entry": {
          "type": "Transfer in",
          "quantity": 1,
          "from": {
            "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

In this case I only need to retrieve one of the two documents that exist in the collection. `code: 1` and `code:2` to be displayed, something like this:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "6386b0e114fe6aee844af06e",
      "transfer": {
        "code": 2,
        "author": {
          "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:29:43.308Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
        },
        "output": {
          "type": "Transfer out",
          "quantity": 3,
          "to": {
            "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        },
        "entry": {
          "type": "Transfer in",
          "quantity": 3,
          "from": {
            "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6386b13e14fe6aee844af06f",
      "transfer": {
        "code": 1,
        "author": {
          "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:27:52.003Z",
          "created_by": "userId",
          "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
        },
        "output": {
          "type": "Transfer out",
          "quantity": 1,
          "to": {
            "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        },
        "entry": {
          "type": "Transfer in",
          "quantity": 1,
          "from": {
            "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
            "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
            "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
            "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
            "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

The original nomenclature of the object corresponds to the following,

```
    [
    {
      "_id": "6386b13e14fe6aee844af06f",
      "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981",
      "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
      "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
      "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
      "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
      "quantity": 12,
      "is_deleted": false,
      "movements": {
        "entries": [...],
        "transfers": [
          {
            "code": 1,
            "author": {
              "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:27:52.003Z",
              "created_by": "userId",
              "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
            },
            "output": {
              "type": "Transfer out",
              "quantity": 1,
              "to": {
                "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            },
            "entry": {
              "type": "Transfer in",
              "quantity": 1,
              "from": {
                "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "code": 2,
            "author": {
              "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:29:43.308Z",
              "created_by": "userId",
              "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
            },
            "output": {
              "type": "Transfer out",
              "quantity": 3,
              "to": {
                "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            },
            "entry": {
              "type": "Transfer in",
              "quantity": 3,
              "from": {
                "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6386b0e114fe6aee844af06e",
      "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981",
      "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
      "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
      "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
      "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
      "quantity": 11,
      "is_deleted": false,
      "movements": {
        "entries": [...],
        "outputs": [...],
        "transfers": [
          {
            "code": 1,
            "author": {
              "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:27:52.003Z",
              "created_by": "userId",
              "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
            },
            "output": {
              "type": "Transfer out",
              "quantity": 1,
              "to": {
                "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            },
            "entry": {
              "type": "Transfer in",
              "quantity": 1,
              "from": {
                "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "code": 2,
            "author": {
              "created_at": "2022-11-30T01:29:43.308Z",
              "created_by": "userId",
              "observation": "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted"
            },
            "output": {
              "type": "Transfer out",
              "quantity": 3,
              "to": {
                "warehouse": "6376d84a4587772c3b2d7175",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e218006a7e9609aaf2f",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            },
            "entry": {
              "type": "Transfer in",
              "quantity": 3,
              "from": {
                "warehouse": "6376d6c5716fea2e60c491c6",
                "warehouse_location": "637d6e1b8006a7e9609aaf2e",
                "expiration_date": "2024-01-03",
                "production_lot": "LOT0544522",
                "product": "6366a7d99795c333b24f0981"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

For this reason, what I do is get to the level of each type of movement, be it transfer, inventory inputs or outputs, and I do it as follows:

```
return this.connect().then((db) => {
      return (
        db
          .collection(collection)
          // The following aggregation uses the $unwind stage to output a
          // document for each element in the movements.outputs array
          .aggregate([
            // Stage 1
            { $unwind: '$movements' },
            // Stage 2
            { $unwind: '$movements.transfers' },
            // Group by code field
            {
              $group: {
                code: ...,
              },
            },
          ])
          // The following project only returns the movements.transfers object
          .project({
            transfer: '$movements.transfers',
          })
          .sort({ 'transfer.code': -1 })
          .toArray()
      );
    });
```

I have tried to use `merge` or `group` but have not been able to do what I expect based on the `code` parameter. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You say "unique identifier", but the whole question is that there are "multiple documents that can be repeated" with each of those `code` values. How are you choosing which one from each group to display? Without any other information, I think [@nimrod serok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74624262/20042973) is currently the most correct. But it effectively just chooses a "random" one from each group, is that acceptable? If so and/or if the intent really is just to have one document per `code` value, perhaps create a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/index-unique/)?

Comment: when a transfer from one inventory to another occurs, it happens that the same code is recorded for both the entry and exit, that is why the query is repeated and I require only one document of the two that are created. @user20042973

Comment: How do you distinguish between the two? It's not obvious to me from the samples. And with the new "_The original nomenclature of the object_" addition - does that represent the structure of the existing document? If so (eg all the codes that you want are in a single document) perhaps a `$limit: 1` after the initial `$match` would be sufficient? Said another way: I'm confident that you can do what you want, it's just not clear what you want (to me at least)

Comment: The original nomenclature of the object is before applying `$unwind` in two stages, starting from the `inventory.movements.[entries, outputs, transfers]`, my problem is that there are two inventories that contain in the transfers array the same `code`. Because from an inventory A to an inventory B there is a transfer movement that shares the same code and movement, therefore I only need to show one of the two.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! I think you can just do a `{ $limit: 1 }` stage (or `{ $sample: 1 }` stage as [@Kal suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74622870/20042973)) then. Like [@nimrod serok said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74624262/20042973), there is probably no reason to `$unwind` if you are going to `$group` things back together again.

Comment: it is also worth noting that there can be many more inventories with many more transfers, as an example I only have two inventories, with 2 movements of type `transfer`, and as I said before, I would only need to show one of each movement, as they are the same code, it would only be one. If I use `$limit` or `$sample` it'll just  show only one document of a lot of `inventory.movements.transfers`

Comment: It is as if in `mysql` you have a `customers` table, where there are two records with the same `card_id`, 
`SELECT COUNT(card_id), name, country, *
FROM customers
GROUP BY card_id;`  the query only returns the customer data without the need to show two records of the same customer.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add two steps to your aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: "$transfer.code", data: {$first: "$$ROOT"}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6CnLyXIjDYk)

But there is no much point in `$unwind` and then `$group` again just after. if you share a **simplified** version of your documents before the `$unwind` steps, and the requested result for them, we can see how to optimize this query before the current step.

Comment: I have updated the question with the original object, before applying the respective aggregations. It is worth mentioning that when a transfer from one inventory to another occurs, it happens that the same code is recorded for both the entry and exit, that is why the query is repeated and I require only one document of the two that are created.

Answer (score -1):

Use Sample https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Add this to your query

```
aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to see if this answers the original quest? OP shows an example and states directly that "_I need only two of the documents_", but this solution will return a single document.

Comment: @user20042973 Can you read? The op says "only need to retrieve one of the two documents"

Comment: Yes, thanks for checking. I was directly quoting the [original text in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74622727/1) that was present at the time this answer was created. The [third revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74622727/revisions), which was created ~1 hour ago and 7 minutes after my comment above (perhaps in response to it), is what changed the text to the version you quoted. The second revision to the question, also after my comment, clarified the structure of the document. That additional info may coincidentally make your solution more viable.

Comment: But the response from mongo is `MongoServerError: Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object` if a use this way

Comment: You have to add the operators in a specific order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228756/mongodb-aggregate-error-each-element-of-the-pipeline-array-must-be-an-object